# Is the Radioactive Potato passed before the goal is checked?

Tags: fluxx

The text on the `Radioactive Potato` says "Any time the goal changes, move this card in the counter-turn direction".

When the rule card `You Also Need a Baked Potato` is in affect, you must have the radioactive potato in addition to the goal requirements to win.

Suppose a player has the `Radioactive potato` creeper and the `Milk` and `Cookies` keepers in front of them, and no other creepers or keepers. On their turn, they play the `Milk and Cookies` goal. Do they win (since they have the goal requirements plus the potato) or do they not (since the potato passed to someone else)?

This is Generic Fluxx v4.0.

Comment: Which variant of Fluxx is this from?  Generic Fluxx does not have a radioactive potato.

Comment: @John This is generic fluxx v4.0

Comment: Interesting, it's not in fluxx v5.0.

Comment: Not in 3.0 either. I guess it was short-lived.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, they do not win.**

The Looney Labs FAQs include [a question about timing issues](http://faq.looneylabs.com/question/669):

> Q. Does the total effect of playing a card have to be resolved before checking for win conditions, or could someone win partway through?
>
> A: As a matter of fact, yes, in Fluxx all consequences of a card play are considered to be functionally simultaneous, so there are a lot fewer timing issues than people sometimes think.
>
> A good rule of thumb is that things in Fluxx (and many other Looney Labs games) are considered to happen simultaneously, so if there are timing issues, assume that things take place all at once, and then consider the outcome.

So the Goal change and the Potato move are simultaneous, meaning that the You Also Need a Baked Potato condition is not met, and the player does not win.